# How to make a JTextField appear when clicking an image?

Tags: java, jtextfield, mouselistener, photo-tagging

So I'm trying to make this program that allows the user to tag photos using java (kinda like Facebook tagging). I have already done loading the image, and making mouselistener when the user clicks an area of the image.

How do I make a JTextField appear when the user clicks a certain area of the photo?

I'm thinking that the JTextField can somewhat be the box where the user can enter his/her name as a tag for the photo.

Also, where do you think I should put the JTextField code? In main?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the X and Y co-ordinates (as said by Daggeto). And then you can show your text field with setVisible(true)

Answer (score 1):

`MouseEvent.getX()` and  `MouseEvent.getY()` returns the horizontal x ant vertical y position of the event relative to the source component.

Then if you your image area described as x1,x2,y1,y2 you can check is clicked position in this area by this 'if':

```
int x0 = MouseEvent.getX();
int y0 = MouseEvent.getY();

if(x0>x1 && x0<x2 && y0>y1 && y0<y2){
    JTextField.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: `public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter{
  
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    object.drawing(x,y);
   }
 } `

So I just basically put that if statement in here? I have not made my JTextField yet though.

Ugh I'm sorry, I do not know how to indent D:

Comment: I think so. And when i said JTextField i meant object of this class.

Answer (score 1):

just use the setVisible() function on the JTextField object and set its value whenever the user a certain portion of the image.